# "new google.maps.Polygon" is undefined until I re-render the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have spent a significant amount of time debugging my function which seems to be exiting at my call to the google maps api.

When I run the function once, it exists at

```
    let bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({ paths: polygonCoordinate });
```

Then once I change something in my code causing a re render of the page and I click to run the function again it works.

I am sure the issue is caused by google maps not rendering prior to the function call. I am just not sure how to render it prior to my call as the user should be taken to the map after the function runs.

I have initialized google globally.

```
    const google = window.google;
```

I load my api key using LoadScript in my main component.

```
    const [ libraries ] = useState(['places', 'geometry']);
    
    <LoadScript
      googleMapsApiKey="AIzaSyD6GLBRhQWQ3Kubf7jD4_DqI-bMo5R7d8Y"
      libraries={libraries}
    >
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
    function insidePolygon2() {

      const originIndexArray = [];
      const destinationIndexArray = [];
      const indexRouteArray = [];
      const matchedRoutePrices = [];

     polygonCoordinatesFormatted.forEach((polygonCoordinate, i) => {

      //function is exiting at this call to google, but once I cause a re render on the page (without refreshing), the google map function is defined and the function runs properly.

      let bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({ paths: polygonCoordinate });

      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(originLat, originLng), bermudaTriangle)) {
        originIndexArray.push(theOgr[i].ogr);
      }

      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(new  google.maps.LatLng(destinationLat, destinationLng), bermudaTriangle)) {
        destinationIndexArray.push(theOgr[i].ogr);
      }
    });

      originIndexArray.forEach((origin) => {
        destinationIndexArray.forEach((destination) => {
          const routeIndex = origin + " - " + destination;
          indexRouteArray.push(routeIndex);
        });
      });

      indexRouteArray.forEach((route) => {
        matchedRouteArray.forEach((matchedRoute) => {
          if (route === matchedRoute.route) {
            matchedRoutePrices.push(matchedRoute.price);
          }
        });
      });

      setMaxPrice(Math.max(...matchedRoutePrices))
    }
```

I have debugged the function and confirm all variables and functions are defined and have the correct values.

Comment: What does your JS console say?

Comment: @MrUpsidown console shows "maps" as undefined when i call "new google.maps.Polygon".

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')

Comment: Doesn't `loadScript` have an `onLoad` or some sort of callback? Sounds like the API isn't loaded when you call `new google.maps...`.

Comment: @MrUpsidown yes, loadScript has an onLoad callback. I am not sure how to leverage it in this situation? I can see that loadScript loads on initial page load, when i run my function and it quits at the google api line I can manually cause a re render and the function runs successfully - but loadScript does not appear to load again.. so I am unclear why it loads initially and the function works only after a re render.

Comment: I don't know much about React but when loading the JS API, you usually load it along with a reference to a callback function. That callback is called once the API script has finished loading which is when you can start to use methods in the `google.maps` namespace. In your case, I suppose that on 2nd render, the API script must be in cache and therefore you don't get the error. Maybe. If you can't fix it, you should provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. Edit your question to include your complete code + provide a runnable codepen/codesandbox or alike.